# how to upload a file to google drive when wifi is available

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api, android-backup-service

I'm creating an app which collects a data and saves in a particular folder. Now I was looking for source code which will automatically uploads to Google drive of a given account(and not the user's managed account) when only WiFi is available.
I can upload a file to Drive but I was specifically looking for this.

Comment: I'm a newbie so I have tried with https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart that too after a lot of trial and error I was able to succeed.

Comment: If you we wish to manage one single repository for all the users (as implied by your question) you probably don't want to use drive. Try firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading, check if WiFi is enabled:

```
 public static boolean isWiFiConnected() {
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (wifiMgr != null && wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled()) { // Wi-Fi adapter is ON

        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();

        if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.getNetworkId() == -1) {
            return false; // Not connected to an access point
        }
        return true; // Connected to an access point

    } else {
        return false; // Wi-Fi adapter is OFF
    }
}
```

don't forget about permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
```